# How to intermix Windows dialogs and VCL forms?

Tags: delphi, winapi, dialog, window, vcl

I want to interoperate with third-party application and to provide a dialog box to it. API wants standard DialogProc and DLGTEMPLATE pointers. However, i'd really like to take advantages of VCL, form designer and such. How can i do this? Which code samples i can study?

Technical:

How can i do:

1. embed VCL form (or frame) into dialog box created from some boilerplate DLGTEMPLATE i supplied.
2. connect VCL WndProc to windows DialogProc.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the interface to the API? What is `DialogProc`? How exactly does the 3rd party code use `DialogProc` and the template you supply to show a dialog? What APIs does it call. Any solution is liable to depend on being able to intercept the dialogs `WM_CREATE` message and merging in your VCL controls.

Comment: @David Heffernan, DialogProc is standard Windows callback, as in DialogBoxIndirect/CreateDialogIndirect. I'm going research if WM_CREATE sent toward my side, will report result later.

Comment: OK, that's clear to me now. I guess I was being a bit dim before, could have worked that out. I'm sure your DialogProc will get enough messages to hook. I think your VCL controls should all receive messages directly. And I guess the queued messages should also land in the right place assuming that `DialogBoxIndirect` runs a reasonable message loop.

Comment: I would say that even if you can get this to work at all you should expect some things not to work. Since you'll be hosted by a non-VCL message loop things that require cooperation from the VCL message loop, e.g. `KeyPreview`, will not work. And it may not work at all. I'm well beyond my comfort zone here and am extemporising.

Comment: This blog I wrote a while ago may be useful even though it does exactly the other way round (use windows dialogs from vcl app) http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2010/03/24/using-windows-dialogs-from-delphi/

Answer (score 0):

Delphi VCL does not interoperate with standard windows Dialogs designed with dialog resource types. Visual studio supports [creating dialog resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d573580h.aspx), still, even in VS 2010, but Delphi never has. Whatever it is that you've got an API for, please mention exactly what it is, and this will (if it isn't some obscure or in-house thing) increase the odds that someone can help you. Since the API expects a dialog handle, and expects to show that dialog and then run your dialog procedure, and send you stuff, you have two choices:

1. Don't use delphi at all. Use visual studio 6, because that's about the era that this API must have been designed for.
2. Use delphi, but use a third party dialog designer from Visual Studio 6 or Borland C++ 4.5, or so, we're talking about 1996 era here, and then write your DialogProc without benefit of any VCL controls or vcl code whatsoever.

I have never ever heard of anybody daft enough to rely on windows dialog resources to build their plugin-screens-in-a-dll-via-an-API. I'd really like to know what app it is you're trying to extend.

You might be able to add a modal dialog box that you show modally, from your code, and such a modally shown sub-dialog (a second level dialog) could use the VCL, but the top level dialog is not even under your control.

Comment: Standard dialog are not "obsolete" and "of 1996 era".

Comment: @Warren "I have never ever heard of anybody daft enough to rely on windows dialog resources to build their plugin-screens-in-a-dll-via-an-API" What would you propose as an alternative? I don't know much else that actually works. Pure VCL would hopeless since it imposes a specific VCL version on the plugin author. Doing that would rule out the vast majority of potential developers since VCL is of minority interest. It's very hard to see how what you have written actually answers the question.

Comment: As an alternative I would propose the use of a simple plugin API that does not dictate whether you use MFC+dialogs or C#+winforms, or delphi  VCL forms, or java swing ui. I would provide a flat C api that does not encode any UI requirements into it whatsoever.

Comment: That's the dialog API! No need for MFC. Just plain C and Win32.

Comment: Yup. Like I said,  Petzold would be proud o' ye.